# Angular Circular Dependency issue in Jest unit tests

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I have the following Angular Components. They compile and run fine in my application. However, when I include the module in my Jest test, I get errors. I don't know if this is an issue with typescript config, Angular, Jest or the combination.

Components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: '<div>Child here.</div>'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor( @Inject(forwardRef(() => ParentComponent)) private 
parentComponent: ParentComponent ) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: '<div>
    <child-component></child-component>
    <child-component></child-component>
  </div>'
})
export class ParentComponent{
  @ViewChildren(ChildComponent) _children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
}

const EXPORTED_DECLARATIONS = [
  ChildComponent,
  ParentComponent
];

@NgModule({
  exports: [EXPORTED_DECLARATIONS],
  declarations: [EXPORTED_DECLARATIONS]
})
export class TestingModule { }
```

As you can see there is a circular dependency. However, it should be fixed with `@Inject(forwardRef(() => ParentComponent))` but this doesn't work.

spec:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TestingModule } from './test';
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';

describe( 'TestComponent', () => {

  let component: TestTestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestComponent ],
      imports: [
        TestingModule
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  } );

  it( 'default', () => {
    expect( fixture ).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

});

@Component({
  selector: 'test-test-1234',
  template: `<parent-component></parent-component>`
})
class TestComponent { }
```

And I get the following error when I run my unit test.

`ReferenceError: ParentComponent is not defined`

I would like to add that if I do the same with Jasmine / Karma I do not get this error.

Answer (score 1):

When I separated these two components into separate files, the issue is resolved.

Comment: Paradoxical but fact, this helped me too. But this creates a circular dependency so this solution is suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in your tests

```
 const el = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
 expect(el.outerHTML).toMatchSnapshot();
```

If you will upgrade to the latest version of angular (now 5.2.9) these test will run out of memory!

Comment: Hi, I've only just seen your response to my question. You make an interesting point. I have recently been having issues with memory and tests taking a long time to run. This may be the root issue. However, I have made your suggested alteration but this changes the snapshots so that they are not formatted correcty. Have you had experience with this and jest-preset-angular library? Thank you for your post.